# Awk - regular expression

Tags: awk

I have two examples:

**1.**

> $ echo "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" | awk '{gsub(/L[^r]r/,""); print}'
>
> em ipsum dolor sit amet

**2.**

> $ echo "Loorem ipsum dolor sit amet" | awk '{gsub(/L[^r]r/,"");
> print}'
>
> Loorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Why the second example does not work the same as the first?

In the first example, the record of `[^r]` is treated as a single character? Is it because one `"o"` is deleted?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`L[^r]r` matches `L` followed by any **single** character that isn't `r` followed by `r` like `Lor`. To match `Loor` you would want `L[^r]+r`. The `+` quantifier means **one or more** characters that are not `r`.

```
$ echo "Loorem ipsum dolor sit amet" | awk '{gsub(/L[^r]+r/,""); print}'
em ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan what are you talking about?

Comment: I had a doubt but clear now. you already descried in your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I HIGHLY doubt you figured out the right answer given your question. You might want to give us some more info so we can help you.

Comment: @EdMorton note that Grijesh Chauhan isn't the OP.

Comment: @EdMorton : I understood `+` after `[^r]` means repetition for one or more times  Mr. sudo_O could also use `*` (for 0 or more times).

Comment: @sudo_O but he DID ask a question and claims he now has the answer to it.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan That is true, it doesn't seem related to your question though. The answer to your question as I understand it would be `L.r`.

Comment: @EdMorton his comments don't make sense and are irrelevant anyway, it seems he was just clarify the original question and my answer!?

Comment: @EdMorton and Sudo_O ... I have no more doubts regarding question. Thanks to both for helping.

Comment: @sudo_O beats me. I only just figured out that the thing in the square brackets was negate-r, I've been reading it as control-r all this time! Need some coffee I guess....